# CGAL example cannot read input files?

Tags: cgal

this is my first stackoverflow question, so I hope the following text meets the question requirements. If not, please tell me what needs to be changed so I can adapt the question.

I'm new to CGAL and C++ in general. I would like to use CGAL 5.0.2 on a Macbook Pro early 2015 with macOS Catalina Version 10.15.4.

So to begin with, I followed the [instruction steps](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/usage.html) given by the CGAL documentation using the package manager [Homebrew](https://brew.sh). Since CGAL is a header-only library I configured it using [CMake](https://cmake.org), as is recommended by the documentation.

It all worked out fine, so I went on trying the recommended examples given in the file CGAL-5.0.2.tar.xz, which is provided [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/releases). I'm particularly interested in the example Voronoi_Diagram_2.
Using the Terminal I executed the command `-DCGAL_DIR=$HOME/CGAL-5.0.2 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .` in the example folder called Voronoi_Diagram_2. Then I executed the command `make`. All went well, no error messages were prompted. But executing the resulting exec file didn't produce any results.

After some research I managed to modify the code in a way that it prints the values of some variables. Problem seems to be that the input file which contains the line segments for which the voronoi diagramm shall be calculated is not correctly read. 
The while loop which I highlighted in the code below by inserting //// signs seems not to be entered. That's why I assume that the variable `ifs` is empty, even though the input file "data1.svd.cin", which can be found in the folder "data" of the example, wasn't.

Does anyone have an idea for the reasons of this behaviour? Any help is appreciated.

This is the vd_2_point_location_sdg_linf.cpp file included in the example, which I modified:

```
// standard includes
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

#include <cassert>

// includes for defining the Voronoi diagram adaptor

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Segment_Delaunay_graph_Linf_filtered_traits_2.h>

#include <CGAL/Segment_Delaunay_graph_Linf_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Voronoi_diagram_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Segment_Delaunay_graph_adaptation_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Segment_Delaunay_graph_adaptation_policies_2.h>
// typedefs for defining the adaptor

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel                  K;
typedef CGAL::Segment_Delaunay_graph_Linf_filtered_traits_2<K>               Gt;
typedef CGAL::Segment_Delaunay_graph_Linf_2<Gt>                              DT;
typedef CGAL::Segment_Delaunay_graph_adaptation_traits_2<DT>                 AT;
typedef CGAL::Segment_Delaunay_graph_degeneracy_removal_policy_2<DT>         AP;
typedef CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DT,AT,AP>                                    VD;

// typedef for the result type of the point location
typedef AT::Site_2                    Site_2;
typedef AT::Point_2                   Point_2;
typedef VD::Locate_result             Locate_result;
typedef VD::Vertex_handle             Vertex_handle;
typedef VD::Face_handle               Face_handle;
typedef VD::Halfedge_handle           Halfedge_handle;
typedef VD::Ccb_halfedge_circulator   Ccb_halfedge_circulator;

void print_endpoint(Halfedge_handle e, bool is_src) {
  std::cout << "\t";
  if ( is_src ) {
    if ( e->has_source() )  std::cout << e->source()->point() << std::endl;
    else  std::cout << "point at infinity" << std::endl;
  } else {
    if ( e->has_target() )  std::cout << e->target()->point() << std::endl;
    else  std::cout << "point at infinity" << std::endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::ifstream ifs("data/data1.svd.cin");
  assert( ifs );
  VD vd;
  Site_2 t;


// /////////// Inserted Comment ////////////////////////////////
std::cout << "In the following the insertion from ifs should take place" << std::flush;

// ///////////////// while loop which doesn't seem to be active //////////////////
  while ( ifs >> t ) { 
// Existing Code to insert the points in the voronoi structure
    vd.insert(t); 

// Inserted Code to check if while loop is entered
    std::cout << "Entered while loop" << std::flush;

}
// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



ifs.close();
  assert( vd.is_valid() );
  std::ifstream ifq("data/queries1.svd.cin");
  assert( ifq );
  Point_2 p;
  while ( ifq >> p ) {
    std::cout << "Query point (" << p.x() << "," << p.y()
              << ") lies on a Voronoi " << std::flush;
    Locate_result lr = vd.locate(p);
    if ( Vertex_handle* v = boost::get<Vertex_handle>(&lr) ) {
      std::cout << "vertex." << std::endl;
      std::cout << "The Voronoi vertex is:" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "\t" << (*v)->point() << std::endl;
    } else if ( Halfedge_handle* e = boost::get<Halfedge_handle>(&lr) ) {
      std::cout << "edge." << std::endl;
      std::cout << "The source and target vertices "
                << "of the Voronoi edge are:" << std::endl;
      print_endpoint(*e, true);
      print_endpoint(*e, false);
    } else if ( Face_handle* f = boost::get<Face_handle>(&lr) ) {
      std::cout << "face." << std::endl;
      std::cout << "The vertices of the Voronoi face are"
                << " (in counterclockwise order):" << std::endl;
      Ccb_halfedge_circulator ec_start = (*f)->ccb();
      Ccb_halfedge_circulator ec = ec_start;
      do {
        print_endpoint(ec, false);
      } while ( ++ec != ec_start );
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  ifq.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: With -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release, cmake helpfully disables all checking. Please use -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug while experimenting, and only switch to Release once it works but is too slow. Maybe one of the assertions will then help you identify the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I switched to DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug and after creating the exec file and running it I get the following error message: Assertion failed: (ifs), function main, file /Users/pascalgoldschmid/Downloads/CGAL-5.0.2/examples/Voronoi_diagram_2/vd_2_point_location_sdg_linf.cpp, line 40. So this seems a step in the right direction. Something is wrong with reading the file. I will do some research on how the assert function works. If anybody has further ideas, please share them, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Most likely it couldn't even open the file because the file isn't where it expects it. Try giving a full path to data1.svd.cin instead of a relative one.

Comment: I tried this and now it works. Thank you very much!